What separator to set in text files with complicated string entries (that include all the standard separators)
I have a large dataset (3.6 billion lines, 20 columns, I'm working in manageable chunks of 1m rows). My cells can include entries like this string:
"sometext  "some other text"... ; , "a" some more text \t . ;"

This is one cell. fread() somehow manages to understand where the next column starts, it is amazing. I want to save my chunks as txt files in a way that any future program (actually the arrow package) that is not as good as fread() in handling such cases will understand where columns end and start but I don't want to change the text within the outer "...". I'm getting lots of errors with different commands, I think this is because all the usual separators are included as characters in my string which however also includes "...". I thought I could just set a nonsensical separator like ";-.-;" or something like that which can never appear in my 3.6bnx20 cells. But apparently it needs to be one character. However, every character imaginable appears somewhere in my 3.6 billion rows at some point. How does one set separators in such a dataset?
p.s.: I guess a case in point is that stackoverflows coloring scheme does not recognize that the cell above should be one string ;)

"How does one set separators in such a dataset?"  Generally, one doesn't.  A separator ideally should not appear in the data.  Or if it does, then every occurence in the data needs to be escaped in some way so that it is not regarded as a separator.  Or one needs to use fixed length fields.  With a dataset the size of yours, that's not really practical.  I think your fundamental issue is "I want to save my chunks as txt files in a way that any future program ... will understand where columns end and start".  I don't believe that is realistic.  Please reconsider.

PS 3.6 billion lines in 360,000 chunks of 100,000 lines each.  Is that manageable?

Thanks! Sorry, it is 1 million lines per 36.000 chunks (edited). Unfortunately, I have no control over the data I get. It is simply the way it is and now I have to deal with it. More specifically about my goal: I want the arrow package to be able to read it, not any program (edited)

Use a different format
The best way around this is to use a format other than a csv, like Parquet. You have said in a comment that your goal is to read it using arrow.
Let's create some sample data with two columns. One is the string you included with some random Unicode characters and emojis added, and the second randomly samples those characters:
library(data.table)
str <- '"sometext \U002 \U003   "some other text"... ; , "a" some more text \t . ;"'
set.seed(2024); N_ROWS <- 100
dat <- data.frame(
    col1 = rep(str, N_ROWS),
    col2 = sapply(seq(N_ROWS), \(., x = str) paste0(sample(strsplit(x, "")[[1]], nchar(x)), collapse = ""))
)

arrow::write_parquet should be able to handle data like this without any pre-processing:
arrow::write_parquet(dat, "./tmp.parquet")
dat_arrow_pq <- arrow::read_parquet("./tmp.parquet") |>
    data.frame()
identical(dat, dat_arrow_pq) # [1] TRUE

You could also use the feather format:
arrow::write_feather(dat, "./tmp.feather")
dat_arrow_feather <- arrow::read_feather("./tmp.feather") |>
    data.frame()
identical(dat, dat_arrow_feather) # [1] TRUE

Writing to csv
Your text may be being mangled
Although in your question you have the right number of columns, I wouldn't assume that reading and writing to/from csv has not mangled the text. If we write dat to csv and read it back in, we have the right number of columns:
fwrite(dat, "./tmp.csv")
dat_dt <- fread("./tmp.csv", data.table = FALSE)
names(dat) # [1] "col1" "col2"
names(dat_dt) # [1] "col1" "col2"

However, using the default fread() and fwrite() options, the quotes are now doubled:
print(dat$col1[1], quote = FALSE)
# [1] "sometext \002 \003   "some other text"... ; , "a" some more text \t . ;"
print(dat_dt$col1[1], quote = FALSE)
# [1] ""sometext \002 \003   ""some other text""... ; , ""a"" some more text \t . ;""
identical(dat_dt, dat) # FALSE

Use a separator that is not in the text
If you must use a plain text format, then you need a separator that either is not in the text, or that can be replaced if it is.
Here, I'll use \U001. This is the start of heading character which is non-printable and obsolete, so is very unlikely to be in your data, and if it is there should be no problem removing it. In the very unlikely event that your data contains this character and it has meaning, Unicode has around a million other characters in many languages that you could choose for the same purpose.
Here is a function to remove "\U001" from your data and then to save the file using it as a separator:
save_clean <- function(df, outfile = "./tmp.csv", sep = "\U001", repl = "") {
    char_cols <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.character)]
    df[char_cols] <- lapply(df[char_cols], \(x) gsub(sep, repl, x))
    fwrite(df, outfile, sep = sep, quote = FALSE)
}

This will allow you to save and read in the file:
save_clean(dat)
dat_dt <- fread("./tmp.csv", sep = "\U001", data.table = FALSE, quote = "", strip.white = FALSE)
identical(dat, dat_dt) # TRUE

This will also work in base R and with readr or arrow:
dat_base <- read.csv("./tmp.csv", sep = "\U001", quote = "")
dat_readr <- readr::read_delim("./tmp.csv", delim = "\U001", quote = "") |>
    data.frame()
dat_arrow_csv <- arrow::read_delim_arrow("./tmp.csv", delim = "\U001", quote = "") |>
    data.frame()
identical(dat, dat_base)      # [1] TRUE
identical(dat, dat_readr)     # [1] TRUE
identical(dat, dat_arrow_csv) # [1] TRUE

If your text may start with a space which you want to keep then it's important to ensure that you set quote = "" and strip.white=FALSE.
A note on character choice
Wasting time with gsub() is inefficient when it is unlikely that "\U001" appears in the data. I suggest you stream the files beforehand to see whether the character needs to be replaced. On Linux/Mac:
grep -P -l '\x01' *.csv

Or on Windows PowerShell:
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.csv -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if (Select-String -Path $_.FullName -Pattern ([char]0x01) -Quiet) {
        $_.FullName
    }
}

These commands will return a list of csv files which contain the character. If none you can just save normally with fwrite(df, "./tmp.csv", sep = "\U0001", quote = FALSE) and skip the potentially expensive substitution. However, given you cannot make any guarantees about which characters might be included in the text, and also as your data is fairly large, then (if it's an option) the best solution is to avoid a plain text format.

wow, very comprehensive, thanks! I am trying to work my way towards a parquet filesystem but the arrow package can't load my chunks because of these separator issues I think. So I thought I'd fix them first.

So you're also tending towards pre-processing the chunks first, then going Parquet, correct?

@Jakob I've updated now I've seen your comment to show that this will work with arrow::read_delim_arrow(). But if that's the goal why not just arrow::write_parquet() or arrow::write_feather()? You shouldn't need to pre-process them for that.

thanks! fread() automatically fixed quotation issues inside strings, arrow (for some specific chunks, not all) threw errors like Invalid: CSV parser got out of sync with chunker. This can mean the data file contains cell values spanning multiple lines; please consider enabling the option 'newlines_in_values'. I assumed this was my separator issue becaue such chunks have cells with quotation marks.

@Jakob but if you want to use arrow then why not use parquet or feather rather (see my edit) rather than csv?

the data came as csv/txt, I now want to build a parquet file from it. But I need to read it first.

So your question is about how to read data like this? My impression was that it was about writing it.

Well I'm deep in a workaround of my arrow reading bug... If I can shortcut it by teaching arrow to read a chunk like that without preparing the data first, fantastic! But I can't read it with arrow.

yep, writing that down makes me think I should solve my arrow reading bug... But your answer does solve my workaround problem. thanks!
